# no obtiene todos los datos un datatable al leer excel con c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, datatable

No me muestra los valores en amarillo al leer excel con c#

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

este es mi datatable al momento de leer el excel desde c#, los registros que comienzan con OHLM00..

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

este es el codigo que uso

```html
                string Provider = "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0";
                String ConnExcel = "";
                HojaExcel = "";
                Session["Msj"] = "Procesando archivo: " + file.PostedFile.FileName;
                string pathOriginal = Server.MapPath("Files/" + file.PostedFile.FileName);
                if (File.Exists(pathOriginal))
                    File.Delete(pathOriginal);
                file.SaveAs(pathOriginal);

                if (file.PostedFile.FileName.Contains("xlsx"))
                    ConnExcel = "Provider=" + Provider + "; Data Source = " + pathOriginal + "; Extended Properties = \"Excel 12.0;HDR=YES;READONLY=FALSE\";";
                else
                    ConnExcel = "Provider=" + Provider + "; Data Source = " + pathOriginal + "; Extended Properties = \"Excel 8.0;HDR=YES;READONLY=FALSE\";";

                ConnLocal = new OleDbConnection(ConnExcel);
                ConnLocal.Open();
                cmdLocal = new OleDbCommand("", ConnLocal);
                System.Data.DataTable dtExcelSheetName = ConnLocal.GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDbSchemaGuid.Tables, null);
                foreach (DataRow drtabla in dtExcelSheetName.Rows)
                    if (drtabla["Table_Name"].ToString().ToUpper().Contains("LAYOUT") || drtabla["Table_Name"].ToString().ToUpper().Contains("SHEET1") || drtabla["Table_Name"].ToString().ToUpper().Contains("TABLE1"))
                    {
                        HojaExcel = drtabla["Table_Name"].ToString();
                        break;
                    }
                if (HojaExcel == "")
                    HojaExcel = "Hoja1$";

                OleDbDataAdapter dta = new OleDbDataAdapter("Select * from [" + HojaExcel + "]", ConnLocal);
                dtExcel = new System.Data.DataTable();
                dta.Fill(dtExcel);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

se agrega propiedad a la cadena de conexion excel IMEX=1

> ConnExcel = "Provider=" + Provider + "; Data Source = " + pathOriginal
>   + "; Extended Properties = \"Excel 12.0;HDR=YES;READONLY=FALSE;IMEX=1\";";

Answer (score 1):

```
Dim dt As New DataTable() 
            Using connExcel As New OleDbConnection(conString)
                Using cmdExcel As New OleDbCommand()
                    Using odaExcel As New OleDbDataAdapter()
                        cmdExcel.Connection = connExcel
                        'Get the name of First Sheet.
                        connExcel.Open()
                        Dim dtExcelSchema As DataTable
                        dtExcelSchema = connExcel.GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDbSchemaGuid.Tables, Nothing)
                        Dim sheetName As String = dtExcelSchema.Rows(0)("TABLE_NAME").ToString()
                        connExcel.Close()
                        'Read Data from First Sheet.
                        connExcel.Open()
                        cmdExcel.CommandText = "SELECT * From [" & sheetName & "]"
                        odaExcel.SelectCommand = cmdExcel

                        odaExcel.Fill(dt)
                        connExcel.Close()

                    End Using

                End Using

            End Using
          GridView1.DataSource = dt
            GridView1.DataBind()
```

Comment: Agrega una descripción de por qué este código resuelve el problema, que hace etc...